# Table of Contents and subappendices

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices

Using the `report` document class, how can I create a table of contents that looks like:

Chapter 1: Title

```
1.1  Title
1.2  Title

Appendices 
1.A
1.B
```

Chapter 2: Title

```
2.1  Title
2.2  Title

Appendices 
2.A
2.B
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Below there's one possible solution; the code includes 1) A redefinition of `\@chapter` (as defined in `report.cls`) to include the word "Chapter" in the chapter entries of the ToC. 2) Two newly defined commands: `\bappendix` and `\eappendix`; the former starts a group, adds "Appendices" to the ToC and redefines `\section` (as defined in `report.cls`) to modify the section counter as requested; the latter simply ends the group:

```
\documentclass{report}

\newcounter{appendix}[chapter]

\makeatletter
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
                         \refstepcounter{chapter}%
                         \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
                         \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}%
                                   {\@chapapp~\thechapter: #1}%
                    \else
                      \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
                    \fi
                    \chaptermark{#1}%
                    \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
                    \if@twocolumn
                      \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
                    \else
                      \@makechapterhead{#2}%
                      \@afterheading
                    \fi}

\newcommand\bappendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}Appendices}
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\section{\stepcounter{appendix}%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{appendix}}
    \@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
      {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
      {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
      {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\eappendix{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\bappendix
\section{Appendix One A}
\section{Appendix One B}
\eappendix

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\bappendix
\section{Appendix Two A}
\section{Appendix Two B}
\eappendix

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the same approach, but using the `etoolbox` package to simplify the code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcounter{appendix}[chapter]

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
{\@chapapp~\thechapter: #1}{}{}
\newcommand\bappendix{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}Appendices}
  \begingroup
  \pretocmd{\section}{\stepcounter{appendix}%
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{appendix}}}{}{}}
\makeatother
\newcommand\eappendix{\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\bappendix
\section{Appendix One A}
\section{Appendix One B}
\eappendix

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\bappendix
\section{Appendix Two A}
\section{Appendix Two B}
\eappendix

\end{document}
```

Here's now a much more simple solution using the `subappendices` environment from the `appendix` package; the `subappendices` environment was slightly modified (to add some vertical space before "Appendices" in the ToC) using the `etoolbox` package; this package was also used to add "Chapter" before the chapter entries in the ToC:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{subappendices}{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}Appendices}
}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@chapter}{\protect\numberline{\thechapter}#1}
{\@chapapp~\thechapter: #1}{}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{Section One One}
\section{Section One Two}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{Appendix One A}
\section{Appendix One B}
\end{subappendices}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Section Two One}
\section{Section Two Two}

\begin{subappendices}
\section{Appendix Two A}
\section{Appendix Two B}
\end{subappendices}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Is it possible to obtain the same formatting with the tocloft package?

Comment: @AlexRichter: yes; Mico's answer, for example, uses `tocloft`. Do you want me to produce a separate example using `tocloft`?

Comment: I wonder if it is possible to combine the appendix package (using begin and end subapendices) and either the etoolbox or tocloft packages to simplify the code.

Comment: @AlexRichter: yes, it's possible. See the third example in my updated answer.

Comment: When I inserted the code to the last example, it didn't add the "Chapter " text in front of each chapter entry in the TOC. Also, it didn't indent the appendix tag.

Comment: The first set of code (without any of the packages) adds the "Chapter" heading but does not indent "Appendix"

Comment: @AlexRichter: I don't understand your last comment. The image I posted was obtained after compilation of the first code and "Appendices" appears with indention. Can you explain with some more detail what do you mean?

Comment: I don't know what happened. I copied your code and didn't obtain your screen shot. I was able to get it to work using the appendix, etoolbox, and tocloft package. So no worries!

Comment: Do you know how to move the beginning of the table of contents, list of figures, and list of tables further up the page? The default is to start those sections above a third of the way down the page.

Comment: I added \hspace{3em} to get the word "Appendices" to indent

Comment: @AlexRichter Yes, I know how to do that. However, as a suggestion, I think that this new request deserves to be in a new fresh question since the original one has been already solved (if this is indeed the case, please consider accepting one of the provided responses). Feel free to start a fresh new question with this new request.

Comment: I posted a new question about the TOC position. What line in your code above indents the word "Appendicies"?

Comment: @AlexRichter: the indentation is achieved by `\addtocontents`; of course, this needs a issuing a regular `\section` before the appendices (as seems to be the case according to your question) to get the indentation of a section; if no `\section` is issued before, the indentation will disappear.

Answer (score 4):

A solution to your question is provided in the following MWE. The MWE also lets you specify when there's only one appendix in a chapter (having the subtitle read "Appendices" when there's only one appendix may look funny).

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{tocloft,ifthen}
    \renewcommand\cftchappresnum{Chapter } 
    \cftsetindents{chapter}{0em}{6em}
    \cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.25em}
    \cftsetindents{subsection}{2.25em}{3em}

\makeatletter
%% For source of "@seccntformat" command, see book "The LaTeX Companion"
\def\@seccntformat#1{\@ifundefined{#1@cntformat}%
   {\csname the#1\endcsname\ \ }%  default
   {\csname #1@cntformat\endcsname}}%    enable individual control
%% Individual control: '\section@cntformat'
\newcommand{\section@cntformat}{\thechapter.\thesection\ \ }

% Macros to redefine numbering of appendix sections
\newcommand{\appname}{} % dummy definition 
\newcommand{\appsecnumbering}[1][0]{%
    \ifthenelse{#1=1}{\renewcommand\appname{Appendix}}
                     {\renewcommand\appname{Appendices}}
    \setcounter{section}{0}
    \renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\Alph{section}}
    \renewcommand{\section@cntformat}{\appendixname~\thesection\ \ }
    \addtocontents{toc}{\medskip\protect{\mdseries\appname\par}}}
\newcommand\normalsecnumbering{%
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}
    \renewcommand{\section@cntformat}{\thesection\ \ }}
\let\origchapter\chapter
\renewcommand\chapter{\normalsecnumbering % first, reset numbering style
    \origchapter} % second, execute the original \chapter command
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section Title} \label{sec:11}
\section{Second Section Title} \label{sec:12}
\appsecnumbering  
\section{Some additional stuff}       \label{sec:1a}
\section{Still more additional stuff} \label{sec:1b}
A couple of cross-references: 
  Section~\ref{sec:11} and Appendix~\ref{sec:1b}.

\chapter{Another Chapter}
\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}
\appsecnumbering[1]  % specify "1" to request singular form of noun "Appendix"
\section{Some singular additional stuff}

\chapter{Yet Another Chapter}
\section{First Section Title}
\section{Second Section Title}
\appsecnumbering[7] % any number other than "1" generates plural form of noun
\section{Some additional stuff}
\section{Still more additional stuff}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note the appearance of the first full page and, in particular, the cross-references to regular and appendix-area sections.

[image]

Finally, if you want the start of the section headers to line up vertically with the headers of the chapters, you should change the line

```
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{2.25em}
```

to:

```
\cftsetindents{section}{0em}{6em}
```

Comment: I wonder if it would be simplier to use the appendix package to number the subappendices?

Comment: With this solution, the optional argument of `\chapter` will produce undesired results.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina -- thanks for pointing out this mistake; I've fixed it in the newly-saved version. (I've also generalized the approach to let the user indicate when there's only one appendix in a chapter.)

Comment: @Mico Hello, could you also tell me how can I add the figures and tables in the appendix to the TOC?

Comment: @WZhao - Without knowledge of your document setup, I'm not in a position to offer actionable advice. Please post a *new query*, in which you state (a) the typesetting issue, or issues, you wish to solve and (b) enough detail about your document to give people the required pieces of information. For sure, do reveal which document class you employ and how you inform LaTeX that a part of the document is an appendix. Thanks.

Comment: @Mico Please see a [new question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/507852) there.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is not too difficult to do using either the `memoir` class, or by calling the appendix package manually (`usepackage{appendix}`) for other document classes.

Note that while `\addcontentsline{toc}` might work for any LaTeX document,

the `subappendices` environment (`\begin{subappendices} ... \end{subappendices}`) comes from either the `memoir` class or the `appendix` package.

```
\newenvironment{coolsubappendices}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\begin{subappendices}
}{
\end{subappendices}
}
```

Here's the specifics of what I actually did, with extra features that aren't directly relevant to answering your question.

```
\newenvironment{coolsubappendices}{
\clearpage
\chapter*{Chapter \thechapter. ~ Appendices}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\namedsubappendices % from memoir class I think
\begin{subappendices}
}{
\end{subappendices}
}
```

E.g. the page break before the chapter's appendices, giving the appendices a within-chapter title labelled by the chapter, using `namedsubappendices` to automatically have the in-text section names be e.g. 'Appendix 1.A' instead of just '1.A' (it still only says '1.A' in the table of contents by default though).

In hindsight this is actually just a dumbed-down version of one of the accepted answer's suggestions, so perhaps I should not have posted this. Anyway here is a minimal example (copied and modified from that answer) using the `report` class

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{appendix}

\newenvironment{coolsubappendices}{
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Appendices}
\begin{subappendices}
}{
\end{subappendices}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{One One}
\section{One Two}

\begin{coolsubappendices}
\section{One A}
\section{One B}
\end{coolsubappendices}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Two One}
\section{Two Two}

\begin{coolsubappendices}
\section{Two A}
\section{Two B}
\end{coolsubappendices}

\end{document}
```